# Right whiskering, unknown naturality

Tags: category-theory, functors

Suppose $F,G:C\to D$ and $H:D\to E$ are functors and $\alpha:F\to G$ is a natural transformation.Let $H\circ \alpha:H\circ F\to H\circ G$ be the right whiskering $(H\circ \alpha)_A:H(FA)\to H(GA)$ defined by $(H\circ\alpha)_A=H(\alpha_A)$.

**Now how it follows by naturality** of $\alpha$ and **functoriality** of $H$ that
$(H\circ\alpha)_A$ is **indeed a natural transformation:**
$$H(\alpha_B)\circ H(F f)=H(Gf)\circ H(\alpha_A)$$
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly.
Functors preserve composition, hence also commutative squares.

By naturality of $\alpha$, we already know $\alpha_B\circ Ff=Gf\circ\alpha_A$. 
Then just apply $H$ on both sides.

Comment: OK. And how do I use the naturality of $\alpha$?

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand, it's easy.